Btop - What is the LAV value mean?
I have a KVM guest and inside it I am running vnc server. I have a ssh tunnel that I connect to it using tigervnc viewer. Everything works good for it except one issue. Using Chrome (using X server), when I vertically scroll on a website it is a bit laggy. I checked the cpu and it looks good, I never see it at 100%... at most 50%. Memory is good to... I usually have about 30 gigs free of ram.
However, I see the first LAV value is 1.88 on btop. What does that mean exactly? Does that mean 100 percent of the cpu is being used and 88 percent of processes are waiting?


This is Load Average and (usually) have meaning of average number of processes for 1, 5 and 15 minutes.
Let me quote part of one page:

On its own, the load doesn’t give any useful information to the user.
The load can change in split seconds. This is because the number of
processes using or waiting for the CPU time doesn’t remain constant.
This is why we use Load Average in Linux to monitor resource usage.

The usual good "maps" is one processor per core, so in your case your system is underutilized
